# Remove Unique Row with Looping Criteria using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-computation

Here is my data

```
## Data
datex <- c(rep("2021-01-18", 61), rep("2021-01-19", 125))
hourx <- c(0,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,16,10,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16)
transaction <- c(1,6,2,5,1,2,1,9,6,12,5,25,14,6,22,9,10,14,15,12,22,12,12,14,9,11,3,3,4,0,1,4,3,1,2,3,3,5,7,5,5,6,9,16,8,13,10,20,15,18,10,19,15,5,13,12,10,12,26,14,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,4,0,6,8,0,2,3,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,6,5,2,0,8,0,0,12,11,0,2,0,11,0,0,14,21,0,0,13,7,0,17,0,0,18,0,7,0,4,4,0,0,7,12,0,13,0,0,13,6,9,0,0,0,16,0,0,16,0,14,0,0,9,0,11,8,0,8,0,0,8,0,10,5,0,15,0,0,3,0,0,8,8,0,0,6,5,0,8,0,0,5,1,0,0,3)
mydata <- data.frame(datex, hourx, seller, product, detail, status, channel, transaction)
```

My task is to add 0 into combination.
This is what i mean. It's a sample, i wanna find changepoint from

From the result, we can see datex "2021-01-18" and "2021-01-19" miss hourx from 17 to 23, So we need to add 0 into hourx 17-23. i Do it manually like this

How do i add 0 into missing "hourx" automatically using dplyr for all combination?
Many Thank You.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your criteria for row removal? Also, it is usual to refer to dataframe rows as "observations", not "data". In your example, you said you want to remove rows which their corresponding date only has a single observation. But if you remove the fifth row, how can that be true? Most of your rows have date "05-mar-21".

Comment: sorry my bad, my english is not good. From mydata at 4th row, we have channel "dombsdpapp2", this is unique, but it doesnt appear the day before. So We removed it. and compare to 9th data, we have channel "dombsdpapp1", it is unique too, but because it had appeared the day before which is had same hourx, so we keep it

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow, from what you describe only rows 1 and 9 would be kept after applying the filter you describe, as this is the only channel that has an entry on both days at the same hour. Why would row 1 or 2 be kept (for example)?

Comment: Ohh sorry, i will edit with some data samples and more explaination. Thanks brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution with rolling computation in this case.  Usage of library `runner` is recommended.

- Firstly, to check your first condition is rather easy.  Create a group_by and create a logical variable say `d1` to check whether such row is unique or not.
- second condition is rather tricky.  So we collect all combinations of `hourx` and `channel` on previous day for any date in a list variable say `d2`.
- lastly, we mutated this list dummy variable into a logical variable to check whether the combination in that day existed previous day or not.  Here I have used `purrr::map2` to mutate on list variable.
- Remaining part is filter only, which is easier to understand because both dummy variables created are logical.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(runner)
mydata %>% mutate(datex = as.Date(datex, "%d-%B-%y")) %>%
  group_by(datex, channel) %>%
  mutate(d1 = n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(d2 = runner(x = paste(hourx, channel),
                     idx = datex,
                     k = '1 day',
                     lag = 1,
                     f = function(x) list(x)),
         d2 = unlist(map2(paste(hourx, channel), d2, ~ .x %in% .y))) %>%
  filter(!d1 & !d2)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  datex      hourx channel     transaction d1    d2   
  <date>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 2021-03-05     5 dombsdpapp2         100 FALSE FALSE
2 2021-03-06    13 dombsdpapp3          10 FALSE FALSE
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the rows instead

```
mydata %>% mutate(datex = as.Date(datex, "%d-%B-%y")) %>%
  group_by(datex, channel) %>%
  mutate(d1 = n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(d2 = runner(x = paste(hourx, channel),
                     idx = datex,
                     k = '1 day',
                     lag = 1,
                     f = function(x) list(x)),
         d2 = unlist(map2(paste(hourx, channel), d2, ~ .x %in% .y))) %>%
  filter(d1  | d2)

# A tibble: 8 x 6
  datex      hourx channel     transaction d1    d2   
  <date>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 2021-03-05     1 dombsdpapp1          50 TRUE  FALSE
2 2021-03-05     7 dombsdpapp1         100 TRUE  FALSE
3 2021-03-05     9 dombsdpapp1          20 TRUE  FALSE
4 2021-03-05     5 dombsdpapp3          75 TRUE  FALSE
5 2021-03-05     9 dombsdpapp3          95 TRUE  FALSE
6 2021-03-05    10 dombsdpapp3          35 TRUE  FALSE
7 2021-03-05    11 dombsdpapp3          60 TRUE  FALSE
8 2021-03-06     1 dombsdpapp1          55 FALSE TRUE
```

- Needless to say you may remove dummy variables `d1` and `d2` created.

Comment: thanks brother, this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```r
mydata <- 
 tibble::tribble(
 ~datex, ~hourx, ~channel, ~transaction,
 "05-Mar-21", 1,  "dombsdpapp1", 50,
 "05-Mar-21", 7,  "dombsdpapp1", 100,
 "05-Mar-21", 9,  "dombsdpapp1", 20,
 "05-Mar-21", 5,  "dombsdpapp2", 100,
 "05-Mar-21", 5,  "dombsdpapp3", 75,
 "05-Mar-21", 9,  "dombsdpapp3", 95,
 "05-Mar-21", 10, "dombsdpapp3",  35,
 "05-Mar-21", 11, "dombsdpapp3",  60,
 "06-Mar-21", 1,  "dombsdpapp1", 55,
 "06-Mar-21", 13, "dombsdpapp3",  10
 )

library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
 group_by(channel, hourx) %>% 
 filter(n() > 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   channel, hourx [1]
#>   datex     hourx channel     transaction
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1 05-Mar-21     1 dombsdpapp1          50
#> 2 06-Mar-21     1 dombsdpapp1          55
```

Comment: good script brother, but how do we delete only 4th data? because on 5 march 2021, 4th data which is the channel "dombsdpapp2" only appears once, not like "dombsdpapp1" and "dombsdpapp2" that appear more than once on 5 march 2021. thanks before